# How to prevent the application from freezing, while checking a lot of PDF files?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I try to create a program checking in a lot of PDF. It can be done from a network drive and take few minutes. The application freeze all during the process and I want to avoid that.

I searched in a lot of posts and videos but I failed to implement it in my program. I tried this code to  understand how it works but it failed too...

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbx.AppendText($"Processing...\n");

    // This webswite takes 1-2s to be loaded
    await HeavyWork(@"https://aion.plaync.com/");

    rtbx.AppendText($"End.\n");
}

public Task HeavyWork(string url)
{
    List<string> lesinfos = new List<string>();

    while (checkBox1.Checked == false)
    {
        using (WebClient web1 = new WebClient())
        {
            lesinfos.Add(web1.DownloadString(url));
        }
        rtbx.AppendText($"{lesinfos.Count}\n");
        this.Refresh();
    }

    rtbx.AppendText($"Done !\n");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

When I click the button, I am never able to click in the checkbox, and the UI never respond.

Comment: All your I/O should use async, too, otherwise it has no chance to yield execution. Try `DownloadStringAsync`.

Comment: + HeavyWork should also be async.

Comment: I use DownloadString instead of DownloadStringAsync because my real program don't have this kind of async function.
In other words, how can I build my own "FunctionAsync" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that you are forced to use a synchronous API, you can keep the UI responsive by offloading the blocking call to a `ThreadPool` thread. The tool to use for this purpose is the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method. This method is specifically designed for offloading work to the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). Here is how you can use it:

```
public async Task HeavyWork(string url)
{
    List<string> lesinfos = new List<string>();
    using (WebClient web1 = new WebClient())
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            string result = await Task.Run(() => web1.DownloadString(url));
            lesinfos.Add(result);
        }
        rtbx.AppendText($"{lesinfos.Count}\n");
        this.Refresh();
    }
    rtbx.AppendText($"Done !\n");
}
```

Notice the `async` keyword in the signature of the `HeavyWork` method. Notice the `await` before the `Task.Run` call. Notice the absence of the `return Task.CompletedTask` line at the end.

If you are unfamiliar with the async/await technology, here is a tutorial to get you started: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Answer (score -1):

Try using `DownloadStringTaskAsync(...)` with an `await (see example below).

```
public async Task HeavyWork(string url)
{
    List<string> lesinfos = new List<string>();

    while (checkBox1.Checked == false)
    {
        using (WebClient web1 = new WebClient())
        {
            var content = await web1.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
            lesinfos.Add(content);
        }

        rtbx.AppendText($"{lesinfos.Count}\n");
        this.Refresh();
    }

    rtbx.AppendText($"Done !\n");
}
```

note: `WebClient` is considered obsolete and it's now [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) to use `HttpClient`.

Comment: Your method uses `await` but it is not marked as `async` (also `return Task.CompletedTask` is a code smell in this case). I doubt that this will even compile =)

Comment: I use DownloadString instead of DownloadStringAsync because my real program don't have this kind of async function.
In other words, how can I build my own "FunctionAsync" ?

Comment: Sorry, but [`DownloadStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync) is **NOT** awaitable. I guess you mean [`DownloadStringTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync)

Comment: @SirRufo correct. updated answer.

Comment: @GuruStron you are referring to code which was provided in the question. I didn't write this method, rather showed the explained changes applied to the method.

Comment: No, I was referring to the code in you original answer.

Comment: @GuruStron Understood. The code within my answer is the same code from the question with minor changes to show how my answer would be applied to the code in question. Not a method I wrote and was providing as a replacement. Nonetheless, your comments are valid and I fully agree with them, but just wanted to clarify that I wasn't suggesting the method as a new solution, rather how to change the provided method.